# Stripe plan dynamic plan with sca

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-sca

My issue:
I am working on a subscription or installment based application so the user gets whatever amount they had to for 3 or 6 months. I used stripe plan and schedule method to accomplish this:

When creating plan if the price is provided manually it works. Subscription is created
But for me sometimes there is calculation and amount varies like dynamic subscription and I want price to be dynamic.

But when I make `amount" => $price,` dynamic I get error
"This payment requires additional user action before it can be completed successfully. Payment can be completed using the PaymentIntent associated with the invoice. For more details see: [https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#requires-action"](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#requires-action%22)

```
     //Fetching intent 
     $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($paymentMethodParams->paymentIntent['id']);
    
    //Create stripe user
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(([
          'email' => 'evansd@ed.com',
          'description' => 'Valued Customer',
          'name' => 'Ed Ward', 
          'payment_method' => $paymentMethodParams->paymentMethod['id'],
          'invoice_settings' => 
              [
                'default_payment_method' => $paymentMethodParams->paymentMethod['id']
              ]
      ]));

      //Attaching paymentIntent with Customer
     \Stripe\PaymentIntent::update($paymentMethodParams->paymentIntent['id'],
        [
          'customer' => $customer->id,
        ]
      );
     $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($paymentMethodParams->paymentIntent['id']);

    $product = \Stripe\Product::create([
      'name' => 'Payment plan for user',
      'type' => 'service'
    ]);

    //Creating plan for the customer
    $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(
      array(
        "product" => [
            "name" => '#1 monthly Subscription'
        ], 
        "amount" => 200,
        'nickname' => 'Payment Plan for order - ',
        "currency" => 'GBP',
        "interval" => 'month', 
        "interval_count" => 1,
        'metadata' => [                  
        ]
      )
    );

     $schedule = \Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::create([
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'start_date' => 'now',
      'end_behavior' => 'cancel',
      'metadata' => [
         'local_id' => 'ABC 12345',                    
      ],
      'phases' => [
          [
              'items' => [
                  [
                      'plan' => $plan->id,
                  ],
              ],
              'iterations'=>2
          ],
      ],
      ]);

 $subscription_id = $schedule->subscription;
 $result = \Stripe\Subscription::update($subscription_id,
    [
        'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],                
    ]
  );
$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($result->latest_invoice->id);
$invoice->pay();
```

What I did so far:

1: I even tried to set the `$price = 1` and in phases '`quantity' => $price * $qty` so it charges my price.
But then its same again.

This issue is only for certain test cards like : `4000 0027 6000 3184.`(issue started when SCA was implemented). The other cards without sca rules works perfectly.
(These card  that requires authentication on all transactions, regardless of how the card is set up.)

2:Created plan first and then created customer with the plan just like in mentioned in
[Stripe Subscription Plans of Varying Amounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801187/stripe-subscription-plans-of-varying-amounts)

I think its not user action, but its dynamic plan price issue.
If the price is static, it works and with sca card.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The behavior you're describing is expected; trying to pay an Invoice off-session with a card that requires authentication will fail.  Are you paying the non-dynamic ones on-session with Stripe.js?

Comment: Yes, its stripe js. First I check with  stripecreatePaymentMethod and create intent. If it requires action I will call stripe.handleCardAction then connect with API to create subscription. "The behavior you're describing is expected". what does that means, do I need to tell customer payment cannot be processed?

Comment: Are you using Subscription Schedules in both the working and non-working scenarios?  Can you update your question with the static price code that works so I can compare it to the dynamic price code that does not work?